# Struts 2 execAndWait + Spring transaction management integration

Tags: java, spring, transactions, struts2

I'm executing an action that takes a while, so I'm using a custom Struts' `ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor`. I launch a custom `BackgroundProcess` that opens a transaction before invocation, and closes it after invocation.

The action I'm calling uses a service that has the following Spring's transaction advice:

```
<tx:method name="search" propagation="REQUIRED" />
```

However, when I execute this action, I get the following error:

```
Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception 
  is org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
```

I'm guessing this happens because Spring is unable to see the transaction that was opened in `BackgroundProcess` and tries to open a new one. Thus, this error occurs.

How can I configure my `BackgroundProcess` so that it opens a transaction that is seen by Spring?

Or how can I stop Spring from interfering when `BackgroundProcess` is being ran?

Answer (score 1):

Spring managed transactions should be configured for spring beans. You can't manage a transaction on beans that were created without context.

So you either have to configure Spring to use the managed instance of the bean or exclude it from transaction advice.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

I added my BackgroundProcess to my beans definitions, but I get the same error: nested transactions not supported. Even when using the same transaction manager that is used in transaction advices... Any idea on what I could be missing?

And how can I achieve the second part? I.e, exclude a particular BackgroudProcess from the transaction advice?

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I made my interceptor (which is defined in a bean) ApplicationContextAware, with my transaction manager autowired. Then I used applicationContext.getBean("backgroundProcess") and passed the transaction manager in the constructor. The background process opened a session using txManager.getSessionFactory.openSession()

Comment: What is the scope of the bean?

Comment: All are prototype

Comment: It should be declared by Struts. Since the interceptor use another instance of the bean.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand... What should be declared by Struts? The background process? Can you point me the way to do that (I googled without success)?

Comment: The success is not possible without deeper understanding Struts internals. I have posted some related information but in your case it&#39;s difficult to say why it happens without additional information.